# when I search with key, I want to get the only value from the mongodb documents

Tags: arrays, mongodb, command, getvalue

I need a MongoDB query to get the only value from the document. I have the following two documents. I want to get the only value of `service` key from the second document.

```
{
    "develop-48" : [ 
        {
            "analytics" : "f58b6fc81b",
            "service" : "3e449ce020e2",
            "cdm" : "03e9e4f9423fd"
        }
    ]
}
```

and

```
{
    "develop-12" : [ 
        {
            "analytics" : "f58b6fc54b",
            "service" : "3e449ce020d3",
            "cdm" : "03e9e4f9423fd"
        }
    ]
}
```

The query that I have tried is 
`db.den.find({},{"develop-12.service":1, "_id": 0})`

and the output that I am getting is `{  }
{ "develop-12" : [ { "service" : "3e449ce020d3" } ] }`

The expected output is `3e449ce020d3`
If it is not possible, suggest me the best possible way to achieve this

Comment: Not possible... MongoDB does not return anything other than a BSON Document, and a single string is NOT a BSON Document.

Comment: is it possible if I have the documents like  {
tag: "develop-12"
"analytics" : "f58b6fc54b",
"service" : "3e449ce020d3",
"cdm" : "03e9e4f9423fd"
}

Comment: `develop-12"` is static or dynamic?

Comment: It is dynamic only